# Tikz arrays inside pgfmathdeclarefunction```

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{yeet}{2}{
\begingroup
\pgfmathparse{1,2,#1+#2}
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
\endgroup
}
\makeatother
\pgfmathparse{yeet(1,2)}\pgfmathresult
```

I have this code and the output is 123.0

I dont know how to get it to output an array instead. I've tried `\pgfmath{yeet(1,2)`
I see that the problem is the parsing but if I dont use pgfmathparse then it never adds the arguments together

Comment: In order to understand why you get `123`, you may want to read **97 Customizing the Mathematical Engine**. The reason is that internally these lists `1,2,#1+#2` gets converted to `{1}{2}{#1+#2}`. Together with a wrong declaration of the parameters (you feed the function with 3 but say `\pgfmathdeclarefunction{yeet}{2}{...`) this explains the result. BTW, you do not need `\makeatletter` here.

Comment: Thank you again Schrodinger... How do I go about correcting this? Baring in mind I want the output to be an array so 1,2,3

Comment: I provided a way to get large arrays into the function in my previous answer. You just pass the name of the macro that contains the array to the function, and expand it inside.

Comment: Okay thank you. FYI I have read Customizing the Mathematical Engine many times now but It just isn't going in. :(

Comment: ```\pgfmathdeclarefunction{yeet}{1}{...}{
\pgfmathparse{#1[2]*5}
}
\def\arr{1,3,6}
\pgfmathparse{yeet({\arr})}\pgfmathresult
```
So I tried this @Schrödinger'scat
but it does not seem to like it and gives error:

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfmath@expression.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.55 \pgfmathparse{#1[2]*5}
                           
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.